# Best practice for transaction handling using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am developing an app which uses Entity Framework for data access. The architecture of the app somewhat like below:

[image]

As depicted in the drawing, the business service can be consumed from either web app, cli app or windows service. What I'm trying to design is, each **service request** should be performed in a single transaction. I'm using dependency injection to inject services to web api controllers. If I use request scoped dbcontext using DI container, it'll do the job for web api, but won't work for service requests coming directly from CLI app or windows services.

What are best practices used to handle service level transactions with Entity Framework?

e.g.

```
// Services
public class UserService
{
    private TaskService _taskService;
    private UserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserService(TaskService taskService, UserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this._taskService = taskService;
        this._userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void MarkInactive(int userId)
    {
        this._taskService.CloseAllPendingTasks(userId);
        this._userRepository.MarkInactive(userId);
    }
}

public class TaskService
{
    public void CloseAllPendingTasks(int userId)
    {
        ...
    }
}

// Consumer
// Scenario 1:
this._taskService.CloseAllPendingTasks(1);

// Scenario 2:
this._userService.MarkInactive(2);
```

In above example, In case of `Scenario 1`, task service should create new transaction for the operation. While in `Scenario 2`, user service should create a transaction and task service should join the already open transaction.

Comment: `If I use request scoped dbcontext using DI container, it'll do the job for web api, but won't work for service requests coming directly from CLI app or windows services.` -- **Why?**

Comment: `While in Scenario 2, user service should create a transaction and task service should join the already open transaction.` -- **Why?**

Comment: @RobertHarvey, 
1. There wouldn't be a RequestContext when I consume the service from CLI app or Win service.
2. In scenario 2, I would want both those operations (changing user's status and closing their pending tasks) to be done in a single atomic transaction.

Comment: EF doesn't need a `RequestContext` to work properly.

Comment: `In scenario 2, I would want both those operations (changing user's status and closing their pending tasks) to be done in a single atomic transaction.` -- Then provide a single service method that performs both tasks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm using AutoFac for DI and it can be configured to provide new instance for every web request. So using that would serve the purpose for web api, as all services requiring DbContext would get same instance when asked for in same web request context. But in case of CLI or Win service, there wouldn't be an Http request context at all.

Comment: No, but there would almost certainly be some sort of method call to a repository or service layer.  Why couldn't you configure AutoFac to provide a new instance every time that method is called?

Comment: @RobertHarvey `Then provide a single service method that performs both tasks` May be I wasn't clear enough, or I'm not following you. My Repositories inject DbContext through constructor injection. In Scenario 2, there is a single service method which does both the tasks, but both tasks are being done in separate services, which have their own repositories. Am I missing something quite obvious here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72488/discussion-between-rumit-parakhiya-and-robert-harvey).

Comment: `If I use request scoped dbcontext using DI container`. That's the problem. Never start the transaction at so high level. Web API, CLI, etc are mere controllers, drivers, but are not bound to the logic. Transactions start where the business start (ideally). This approach is very similar to the anti-pattern [Open session in view](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/); which it was very common some years ago.

Comment: What did you do finally?

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

This is a problem I've encountered and solved. In short, the issue was indeed that a context was being injected (via an injected repository) which was kept alive in a Windows service consumer, which was not the intention.

The short and simple answer on how I fixed this is to **inject a context factory instead of a context**.

For my use case, I relied on NInject to handle my dependency injection. I chose NInject because it has an extention which automatically generates factory methods when you inject `Func<IFoo>` instead of `IFoo`.

---

### Practical example

To show some code, this is the old way which works for a web context but not a Windows service context:

```
public class PersonService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public PersonService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public Person GetById(Guid id)
    {
        return _uow.PersonRepository.Get(p => p.Id == id);
    }
}
```

The issue here is that the unit of work (and its db context) stays alive for as long as the `PersonService` object stays alive. As you've found out, this creates issues for threads that are kept alive (like a Windows service).

I changed the code so that **a call to the service is able to instantiate its own unit of work**. In other words, even if the same `PersonService` object is kept alive, each subsequent call to a (public) method of the service will create its own unit of work (and db context)

```
public class PersonService
{
    private readonly Func<IUnitOfWork> _createUnitOfWork;

    public PersonService(Func<IUnitOfWork> uowFactory)
    {
        _createUnitOfWork = uowFactory;
    }

    public Person GetById(Guid id)
    {
        using(var uow = _createUnitOfWork())
        {
            return uow.PersonRepository.Get(p => p.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

The NInject extension I used ([NInject.Extensions.Factory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/)) automatically generates a simple factory method.

Assuming my dependency is set up to inject a `UnitOfWork` when asking for an `IUnitOfWork`, then the automatically generated factory method will be `() => new UnitOfWork();`

This solves the issue at hand. Even if a Windows service keeps the same `PersonService` object alive, every time it asks something of the service (= when it calls a public method), you are guaranteed to work in a separate (and fresh) context.

**Some remarks**

- My example uses NInject, but this can be done with any DI-framework that is able to handle deferred execution methods such as `Func<T>`.
- When your service has private methods which require database access, you should pass your `uow` object from the public method to the private method. This ensures that you can maintain the "one execution, one context" approach even if you have many methods which are expected to work with the same context.